# emails are deliverying in gmail spam folder from my vps, even after adding DKIM and SFP records

Tags: email, spf, dkim

I have a VPS, where we have hosted multiple domains. We are facing problem with our email, as emails from few of our domains are always delivering in spam box in gmail. We have added DKIM and SPF for all of the domains. After failing to fix the issue from my end, I had tried to contact with my hosting provider too(Host IT Smart). They are also unable to find out any solution yet. Can you please suggest me to fix this issue. Below are the response from verifier.port25.com

---

```
This message is an automatic response from Port25's authentication verifier
service at verifier.port25.com.  The service allows email senders to perform
a simple check of various sender authentication mechanisms.  It is provided
free of charge, in the hope that it is useful to the email community.  While
it is not officially supported, we welcome any feedback you may have at
<verifier-feedback@port25.com>.

Thank you for using the verifier,

The Port25 Solutions, Inc. team

==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================

HELO hostname:  vps.technowebs.in
Source IP:      23.236.190.220
mail-from:      support@easyretail.in

----------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass
ID(s) verified: smtp.mailfrom=support@easyretail.in
DNS record(s):
    easyretail.in. SPF (no records)
    easyretail.in. 11089 IN TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +23.236.190.220 ~all"
    easyretail.in. 0 IN A 23.236.190.220

----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=support@easyretail.in
DNS record(s):

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass (matches From: support@easyretail.in)
ID(s) verified: header.d=easyretail.in
Canonicalized Headers:
    date:Fri,'20'26'20'Feb'20'2016'20'20:12:29'20'+0530'0D''0A'
    from:support@easyretail.in'0D''0A'
    to:<check-auth@verifier.port25.com>'0D''0A'
    subject:t'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'c=relaxed/simple;'20'd=easyretail.in;'20's=default;'20't=1456497749;'20'bh=nosD6jtIMS+OOhW+x6qFyWo2Lid2rGvD39dKQAIrzIo=;'20'h=Date:From:To:Subject;'20'b=

Canonicalized Body:
    t'0D''0A'


DNS record(s):
    default._domainkey.easyretail.in. 14400 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCsF6ZDVntzQYgh7niTVm4zEGxx3tpKuRDEtjj2lCNSGotO409tcZNAf2TZwsXCMRqOFmlgcRbbvGCI3Ze1l4EiW/msO2/KpFnf0mJ0iDQ4GH7zj7WBIql+yoZAaoYmyYsX7RWeVn9J+yYQcjSYL8/znm1nVZVwi8LLGRyB8+O4ZQIDAQAB"

Public key used for verification: default._domainkey.easyretail.in (1024 bits)

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.

----------------------------------------------------------
Sender-ID check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass
ID(s) verified: header.From=support@easyretail.in
DNS record(s):
    easyretail.in. SPF (no records)
    easyretail.in. 11089 IN TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +23.236.190.220 ~all"
    easyretail.in. 0 IN A 23.236.190.220

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin v3.4.0 (2014-02-07)

Result:         ham  (-2.0 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-1.9 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
                            [score: 0.0000]
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
                            domain
 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
 0.0 BODY_SINGLE_WORD       Message body is only one word (no spaces)

==========================================================
Explanation of the possible results (from RFC 5451)
==========================================================

SPF and Sender-ID Results
=========================

"none"
      No policy records were published at the sender's DNS domain.

"neutral"
      The sender's ADMD has asserted that it cannot or does not
      want to assert whether or not the sending IP address is authorized
      to send mail using the sender's DNS domain.

"pass"
      The client is authorized by the sender's ADMD to inject or
      relay mail on behalf of the sender's DNS domain.

"policy"
     The client is authorized to inject or relay mail on behalf
      of the sender's DNS domain according to the authentication
      method's algorithm, but local policy dictates that the result is
      unacceptable.

"fail"
      This client is explicitly not authorized to inject or
      relay mail using the sender's DNS domain.

"softfail"
      The sender's ADMD believes the client was not authorized
      to inject or relay mail using the sender's DNS domain, but is
      unwilling to make a strong assertion to that effect.

"temperror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is likely transient in nature, such as a temporary inability to
      retrieve a policy record from DNS.  A later attempt may produce a
      final result.

"permerror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is unrecoverable, such as a required header field being absent or
      a syntax error in a retrieved DNS TXT record.  A later attempt is
      unlikely to produce a final result.


DKIM and DomainKeys Results
===========================

"none"
      The message was not signed.

"pass"
      The message was signed, the signature or signatures were
      acceptable to the verifier, and the signature(s) passed
      verification tests.

"fail"
      The message was signed and the signature or signatures were
      acceptable to the verifier, but they failed the verification
      test(s).

"policy"
      The message was signed but the signature or signatures were
      not acceptable to the verifier.

"neutral"
      The message was signed but the signature or signatures
      contained syntax errors or were not otherwise able to be
      processed.  This result SHOULD also be used for other
      failures not covered elsewhere in this list.

"temperror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is likely transient in nature, such as a temporary inability
      to retrieve a public key.  A later attempt may produce a
      final result.

"permerror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is unrecoverable, such as a required header field being
      absent. A later attempt is unlikely to produce a final result.


==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

Return-Path: <support@easyretail.in>
Received: from vps.technowebs.in (23.236.190.220) by verifier.port25.com id hq1i5c20i3gi for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Fri, 26 Feb 2016 09:42:30 -0500 (envelope-from <support@easyretail.in>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=support@easyretail.in
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed) header.From=support@easyretail.in
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=pass (matches From: support@easyretail.in) header.d=easyretail.in
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; sender-id=pass header.From=support@easyretail.in
Received: from www.easyretail.in (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
        by vps.technowebs.in (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 8C6093C2593
        for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Fri, 26 Feb 2016 20:12:29 +0530 (IST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=easyretail.in;
        s=default; t=1456497749;
        bh=nosD6jtIMS+OOhW+x6qFyWo2Lid2rGvD39dKQAIrzIo=;
        h=Date:From:To:Subject;
        b=L/XoimrjmAdUbjHxyfObm/LTNlJ25vRQCV91JBE+lv82/WLMCOGSLP56LULw1DvWC
         aDM9rpn3oIaS6Pw+Iqo120fFjvbhH1WotrmoknGEVDsqBPh1V0UYFoA7hVkLeUcoIi
         y0ZVzMDvcDIjQxN0v+vcqdJ5K10WYUJ7uCOqZHO8=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 20:12:29 +0530
From: support@easyretail.in
To: <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>
Subject: t
Message-ID: <f3def6547d7c92cb00e29668a7bf7ded@easyretail.in>
X-Sender: support@easyretail.in
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/0.8.5
```

---

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best Regards,
Rajib Deb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gmail has its own spam detection system, and your DNS/mail server configuration looks good and solid. From those facts I would assume that
 - either you're sending (as a message subject/body) something that is considered as SPAM-related by gmail
 - or your domain/ip address has a bad history with gmail (let's say during the process of configuration of your server you've tried to send some test emails with not properly configured mail domain too early). Gmail has recorded those bad attempts, and due to the past history considers them as spam.

I would suggest to send several emails to your own gmail account, and remove those emails from spam folder there (not a spam), that might tell the gmail spam detection engine to stop considering the emails coming from your domain as SPAM.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, lets see what happens next.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail have now a postmaster tool you can check your domain/ip Reputation history, spam rate and in the "Authentication" area you can check DKIM/SPF/DMARC works correctly.

https://gmail.com/postmaster/

I recommend to use the CNAME record for authentication, if you are using the default TXT record also on SPF query this entry return.